# EE 2.7.2 Upgrade - Channel Form File issue

Tags: channel-form, ee2-upgrades, safecracker-file, saef

Update to 2.7.2 and keep getting an error in a Channel Form with a file field. The initial error is a javascript error. If I try to click on the "close" I am sent to the top of the page with a hash tag (#) appended to the URL.

In the channel form the field is : `{field:artist_pic}` where `artist_pic` is a file field.

If I remove the `safecracker_file` folder from the `third_party` folder, I get a page breaking error such as:

```
Error

Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.safecracker_file.php.
Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the expressionengine/third_party/ directory
```

What do I need to do in order to correct this?

*** EDIT ***

The update was from v2.5.5 when performed. The field is a file field and not a saefcracker field.

As for the js error received it is an unknow error `W3C is an unknown...` basically, not seeing the 'file' it is looking for.

*** EDIT II ***

Ok, so after speaking with my partner on this, it looks as though the previous file was never updated to a standard file field. He is making that change now. SOOOOOOO, to keep with the spirit of awarding answers on EESE, who knows if changing field types from saefcracker file fields to a standard file field keeps the data already associated to all of the entries?

Comment: I'm unclear if you are using a File field or a SafeCracker File field... posting some info that may be relevant as an answer below.

Comment: Also, what is the JS error you are seeing? Also, why are you removing the "safecracker_file" folder?

Comment: I was removing the folder to test what would happen. There are several posts in the EESE forum in which people were instructed to remove it as it is no longer needed since the merge to native fields.

Comment: One thing's for sure, you shouldn't have safecracker file field type add-on installed after the 2.7.x upgrade. It's possible that the page error and javascript error are actually unrelated.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when I output the logs and examine the error in the console, it (the js error) is precisely where the file output is at.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you forgot to upload the /themes directory when you upgraded EE. Try reuploading all the files in that directory to be eliminate that as the source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

OK... for all those out there, I apologize for the lack of communication and not changing the field type.

The data does carry over. The field type processed correctly. Once the old saefcracker fields were updated to file fields the entries had to be re-saved in order to process them as file fields. Also, the saefcracker folder had to be returned to the third party folder in order to update the fields that were included within the Matrix fields. This however, could have been due to not updating Matrix yet.

Hopefully this will help anyone else who runs into a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which EE version you updated from but here's some info that might help.

In v2.7.0 the SafeCracker File fieldtype was merged with ExpressionEngine’s native File field as per this blog entry (**http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.7.0-released**). I don't know what that means exactly but it may be related to your issue.

Here's the change log for that 2.7.0 version:
**http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-7-0**

Comment: Hey there Anna... Sorry about that. The update was from v2.5.5 and it is a file field, not a safecracker field.     ;)

I'll update the OP